# Kafka KStreams left join does not give me expected output

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Stream 1:

Key: A, Value: 1

Key: B, Value: 2

Key: A, Value: 3

Key: B, Value: 4

Stream 2:

Key: A, Value: X

Key: B, Value: Y

Output that I get:

Value1: 1, Value2: X

Value1: 2, Value2: Y

Value1: 3, Value2: Null

Value1: 4, Value2: Null

Expected Output:

Value1: 1, Value2: X

Value1: 2, Value2: Y

Value1: 3, Value2: X

Value1: 4, Value2: Y

```java
JoinWindows joinWindows = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5));
KStream<String, String> joined = stream1
.join(stream2,
    (value1, value2) -> {
        System.out.println("value1: " + value1);
        System.out.println("value2: " + value2);
        return value1; //Ignore this for now, my prints are not showing me the correct value
    },
    joinWindows
);
```

this is my implementation

Answer (score 0):

Without record timestamps, the question is somewhat incomplete... Also, what version of Kafka Streams are you using? Older versions implement stream-stream join slightly differently, and emit so-call "eager results" which can be considered spurious (I believe this is what you observe).

The behavior was changed in 3.1 release, and you can enable it using `JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(...)` or `JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(...)` instead of `JoinWindows.of(...)` (which is deprecated as-of 3.1 release).

For more details about joins, check out https://www.confluent.io/events/kafka-summit-europe-2021/temporal-joins-in-kafka-streams-and-ksqldb/